# How to refresh pictures in the service worker

Tags: angular, browser-cache, angular-service-worker

I'm setting up a PWA with Angular 7. Here is my problem: 
If a User is logged in the Application, he can Upload a profile picture. The picture will be uploaded in the /assets folder, which is cached by the service worker.

As I understand the service worker, the application itself recognizes updates by the filenames in the project main folder. If the filenames changes, the service worker gets the new version.

Maybe you see the problem now: If a User uploads a picture, no filename will change because it is no update from the Angular project. So the User see his "old" profile picture for a long time OR if he refreshes the browser cache.

I tried to upload the profile pictures with php in the angular assets folder. Is this the correct way?

This code works very well for me, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to save pictures with a PWA. I want the service worker cache for my pictures, but if a User uploads a picture I want an instant refresh.

```
$path = '../assets/img/profile_pictures/';

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $originalName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ext = '.' . pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $generatedName = $_POST['id'];
    $filePath = $path . $generatedName . '.png';

    if (!is_writable($path)) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => false,
            'msg' => 'Destination directory not writable.'
        ));
        exit;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => true,
            'originalName' => $originalName,
            'generatedName' => $generatedName
        ));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(
        array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No file uploaded.')
    );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why are you saving pictures in the apps folder directory instead of a db?

Comment: I think I just don't know what the best practice is to store pictures. Frontend File System (Like the Angular assets folder), Backend File System or in the Database as blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to achieve is allowing a user to update their profile picture. This shouldn't be stored anywhere in your Angular frontend - it should be stored in a backend database somewhere, and then you make a request to load that picture when a user goes to the containing page.

This way, every time they go to the page, they make a new request for data. Unless they have no internet connection; in which case the service worker will return you its latest cached image (if you have set the query URL to be cached in your ngsw-conf.json).

If you don't want to make your own backend service to do this; you can use a service such as Firebase, which has several libraries for communication with Angular. You can check this out with code samples here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: Thats exactly what I want.

I have a laravel backend service. Is it best practive to save the image as blob in the data base _or_ to save it in the laravel project in a folder?

Comment: @Iloivar definitely save it as a blob in your database. Much more efficient and allows you to include it in any queries you may need. It's much more maintainable. Imagine if Facebook stored everyone's pictures in a folder - we'd never get them!

Comment: I thought about your answer and googled a little bit. I am not sure anymore if it is the best way to store images in the database. The traffic through the network would be very high. If the pictures are on a webserver and i just "call" them in the html in the img tag there is no traffic. Is this correct ? But if the images are on a webserver I have a problem with the service worker and updated pictures. I am very confused. :-D

Comment: The approach of storing your images in the assets folder just isn't scalable - the assets folder is meant for things such as fonts, static images (i.e your logo). The traffic will be high if there's many requests - that's why I suggested a service such as firebase as it may keep your costs down.  I would say storing the user images in the assets folder is really bad practice - avoid doing that even though it is tempting due to how easy it is (short term)